# Отбросить лишние данные в DataFrame Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Есть столбец в Фрейме, где года записаны в таком виде: 1927/28
Тип данных object
Нужно оставить только 1927 во всем Фрейме, то есть отбросить все после знака '/' ну и сам этот знак
Спасибо за помощь

Comment: Вопрос должен включать пример исходных данных

Answer (score 0):

при исходном датафрейме:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"years":["1927/28", "1928/29", "1929/30", "1930/31", "1931/32"]})
```

```
     years
0  1927/28
1  1928/29
2  1929/30
3  1930/31
4  1931/32
```

Есть по меньшей мере пара-тройка способов:

```
# 1
df["years"] = df["years"].str.split("/").str[0]
```

```
#2
df["years"] = df["years"].str.replace(r"/.+","", regex=True)
```

```
#3
df["years"] = df["years"].str.extract(r"(.+)/.+")
```

все дадут

```
  years
0  1927
1  1928
2  1929
3  1930
4  1931
```